# Getting email alert when a end time is about to reach

Tags: events, notifications, reminder

I want to create an email notification to remind a group of people on Sharepoint webform when an end date is imminent in Sharepoint 2013 online. I want to know how can I do this as I have created a team calendar on SharePoint using a list

I also want to know whether it will be a workflow or a reminder/alert for this task. As I am new to the Sharepoint I really need help regarding this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would help to include which version of SharePoint, and whether on-premises or online.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your reply. It is sharepoint 2013 online. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in alert only alerts users who have subscribed to alerts on a list.  If your account has sufficient priveleges, you can programatically set up alerts for other users, but those alerts still won't be conditionally based on a date field, it would just alert when an event is created or modified.

If you are using SharePoint Online, the easiest way to implement this would be to create a Flow in Power Automate, using the scheduled trigger to run your Flow on a daily basis to query against the list for items whose date meets your criteria, then send emails to the specified users.  This way you also have nearly full control over what they email says and how it is formatted.

There is a [template in PowerAutomate for scheduling reminders](https://us.flow.microsoft.com/en-us/galleries/public/templates/45a3399aa29345308f08b6db0a9c85b9/get-daily-reminders-in-email/), that would be a good place to start, and here is a blog post about a Flow doing a similar type of [alert using an expiration date in SharePoint](https://www.sharepointsiren.com/2018/03/using-flow-to-send-email-reminder-from-sharepoint-data/).

Comment: Hi, your answer was the most helpful.

Comment: Although I have used the SharePoint designer 2013 workflow for this task and it worked very well.

On updating item it gets paused until the end time and then when the end time reaches it gets active again and send email to the people who we want to it to send to.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with out of the box reminder notification settings in just four steps :

1. **Select a list about which items you will be notified.**
2. **Define the recipients of your SharePoint reminder.**
3. **Customize your SharePoint reminder email view.**
4. **Define a schedule and conditions to send this SharePoint reminder.**

For details steps, please refer the below article :

[How to Set Up SharePoint Reminder Email](https://blog.virtosoftware.com/how-to-set-up-sharepoint-reminder-email/)